# How to display a video stored in Laravel Voyager as a file in frontend?

Tags: laravel, video, display, voyager

I want to display a multiple videos stored with Laravel Voyager in the frontend,
I'm attempting to pull out my videos uploaded through admin with this:

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{ Voyager::image( $video->file) }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
@endforeach
```

But it doesn't work, can someone help?

Comment: When you say, "it doesn't work" what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: this is my code :`@foreach ($videos as $v)


      <?php $file = (json_decode($v->files))[0]->download_link; ?>

        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="{{ Voyager::image( $file ) }}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

@endforeach`

Comment: Hey @PRANKHB it would be helpful if you dumped the $video model `$v` using the `dd($v)` function and included the output here

Answer (score 1):

you can call it directly from storage like this :

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{ Storage::url($video->file) }}" type="video/mp4">
       // Or 
   <source src="{{ asset("storage/$video->file") }}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
@endforeach
```